# How to merge this two jquery function to color the background of a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to give background color to the div when the checkbox from table is checked.

Here is the HTML:
(checkbox that will effect the background color of div)

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="" ></div>
 <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="" ></div>
 <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="" ></div>
 <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="" ></div>
</div>
```

(checkbox that is in table)

```
<table id="main1">
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' value="1" ></td>
 </tr>    
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' value="2" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' value="3" ></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' value="4" ></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and the jQuery

(for vice-versa checking of table and div checkboxes)

```
    $(function() {
      var checkboxes = $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        checkboxes.filter(function() {
          return value == $(this).val()

        }).not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
      });
    });
```

(for giving the background color to the div when the checkbox from div is checked)

```
    $("#main input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
      var that = this;
      // alert(that.value);
      $(this).parent().css("background-color", function() {
        return that.checked ? "rgb(251, 252, 170, 0.7)" : "";
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="main">
  <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="">1</div>
  <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="">2</div>
  <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="">3</div>
  <div id="1"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="">4</div>
</div>


<table id="main1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' value="1">t1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' value="2">t2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' value="3">t3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' value="4">t4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var that = this;
      if ($(this).parent()[0].nodeName !== "TD") {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", function() {
          return that.checked ? "rgb(251, 252, 170, 0.7)" : "";
        });
      }

      $("div input[value='" + value + "']").parent().css("background-color", function() {
        return that.checked ? "rgb(251, 252, 170, 0.7)" : "";
      });



      checkboxes.filter(function() {
        return value == $(this).val()

      }).not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The div should have a background color not the table and if I check the checkbox from table as I've said the div would have a background color too. Thank you!

Comment: Please check now. It was my mistake . :( I have updated it now.

Comment: If I click the table checkbox. The div should have background color too.